# Find size of each row from DataTable

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlbulkcopy

I have to find the batch size for a bulk copy dynamically to avoid possible Timeout period elapsed error. 
I was planning to do it by finding the row size. If size of each row is more, then decrease the size of batch.

Here is what i tried

```
var values = new object[data.Length];
// add row values to values 
dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
if (Marshal.SizeOf(values) > 2000)
   moreThan2000++;
```

based on `moreThan2000` i will update the batch size. But when i tried `Marshal.SizeOf` or `sizeof` for values, i'm getting below error

> Type 'System.Object[]' cannot be marshaled as an unmanaged structure;
>   no meaningful size or offset can be computed

1. Is there any way to find the row size from DataTable?
2. Is there any existing way for finding the batch size dynamically based on system specification and input?

Comment: `Marshal.SizeOf` is not useful -- for many simple types this comes out more or less as the size of the TDS row on the wire, but it's no good for, say, strings, where the size depends on whether you're using `VARCHAR` or `NVARCHAR`. What really matters here is the native type ultimately used for the bulk copy. (Also, `DataTable` is a hideously inefficient way to serve up rows for a bulk copy and suitable only for small batches; look into `IDataRecord`.) Adjusting bulk copy timeout based on total size is not something that sounds very useful to begin with -- why not just set the timeout to 0?

Comment: @JeroenMostert, Can you share how effective if IDataRecord over DataTable?

Comment: `IEnumerable<IDataRecord>` consumes no memory except what you need for one row; `DataTable` consumes memory linear to the amount of data in it. If you're generating or streaming data from an external source, `IEnumerable<IDataRecord>` beats `DataTable` hands down on memory use (and time by eliminating garbage collection). How much of a difference this makes depends on your scenario and should be tested. For small batches, the overhead of `DataTable` won't matter. For very large data sets, simply cutting out the time for filling the `DataTable` can be measurable, let alone the copying itself.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any accurate method to calculate the size of a managed object, but you can get a rough estimate using [GC.GetTotalMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.gettotalmemory?view=netframework-4.8).

Something like this:

```
long start = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);

var values = new object[data.Length];
// add row values to values 
dataTable.Rows.Add(values);

long used = GC.GetTotalMemory(true) - start;
```

`used` will be your used memory.

Comment: The amount of memory used by `DataTable` and all its sub-objects has only a very tenuous relationship to the size of the data sent in the bulk copy, as the data layout is completely different (a TDS bulk copy packet is a flat array; `DataTable` uses a red/black tree, plus managed bytes don't have a one-to-one relation to what's sent in TDS). With a lot of experimenting you might be able to get at a magical value that would indicate the batch is "too big", but it would be quite unreliable. Probably much worse than (say) just adding the lengths of all strings together.